# gem install bundler error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

unable to install bundler gem, this is the error that occurs once I install it :

```
Fetching: bundler-1.10.6.gem (100%)  
ERROR:  Error installing bundler:
    invalid gem: package is corrupt, exception while verifying: undefined method `size' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) in /Users/hadifarhat/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/cache/bundler-1.10.6.gem
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your download has been interrupted, remove the `bundler-1.10.6.gem` file and try again.